# Implementing defined values in boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a question about boxplot. Let's take the code following :

```
qplot(y=rnorm(100),geom="boxplot")+theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                                        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                                        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+scale_y_continuous(breaks=round(c(median(residuals),summary(residuals)[2],summary(residuals)[5],max(residuals),min(residuals)),digits=2))
```

[image]

I want to include all information into the boxplot. But when I'm trying to include quantile information instead of having values of 1st and 3rd quantile I get text "1st" and "3rd" quantile. Is there any easy way how I can change that text into numbers of proper quantiles ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The summary command returns a named number vector. For each element in the vector, there is a name associated with it. To find the names of each element you can write:

```
names(summary(residuals))
#>[1] "Min."    "1st Qu." "Median"  "Mean"    "3rd Qu." "Max."
```

Then, in order to print the values in the axis, you should access them by their names rather than by their index.
So you can write your code as following:

```
qplot(y=rnorm(100),geom="boxplot")+theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+scale_y_continuous(breaks=round(c(median(residuals),summary(residuals)[['1st Qu.']],summary(residuals)[['3rd Qu.']],max(residuals),min(residuals)),digits=2))
```

Here is the result: [image: 1]